# Windows Phone, como importar dados (IsolatedStorageFile)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone, importação

Existe alguma forma de eu importar um arquivo com dados (txt) para a memória interna do Windows Phone usando "IsolatedStorageFile"?
Eu preciso importar uma lista de clientes, e ser capaz de editar pelo aparelho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Isolated Storage é como podemos gravar informações de nossas aplicações para Windows Phone no aparelho, sem a necessidade de se utilizar um banco de dados SQL Server Compact para isso.

Isto economiza uma grande quantidade de tempo que teríamos para criar uma estrutura de banco de dados e configurar o acesso a dados pela nossa aplicação porém não deve ser usado como um substituto para um banco de dados.

**Para utilizar o Isolated Storage é necessário fazer referência.**

```
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
```

**Para armazenar dados da nossa aplicação basta utilizar como no trecho de código abaixo:**

```
IsolatedStorage iso = IsolatedStorage.ApplicationSettings;
if(!iso.Contains("LISTA_CLIENTES"))
{
     iso.Add("LISTA_CLIENTES", new List<string>());
}
```

**Para recuperar informações basta acessar pela chave que foi criada:**

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
if(iso.Contains("LISTA_CLIENTES"))
{
     list = iso["LISTA_CLIENTES"];
}
```

**Para gravar informações em uma chave existente:**

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();if(iso.Contains("LISTA_CLIENTES")){     iso["LISTA_CLIENTES"] = list;}
```

[FONTE](http://matheusdev.blogspot.com.br/2014/01/como-usar-isolated-storage-windows-phone.html)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas isso quer dizer que não há possibilidade de importar dados para a memória interna?